# why chrome developer tools cannot find certain element sent from server?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I was using the chrome developer tool to inspect the request and response of [this website](https://www.pawmenow.com/what-dogs-can-eat/).

I was expecting to see an HTTP response containing the word shown on the webpage. For example, when I submitted "banana", the webpage shows "Yes! Dogs can eat banana".

However, I couldn't find any HTTP response from the chrome developer tool; what I got during this process was only an SVG file. I was doubting the text content was encoded in the SVG file, but nothing was found.

I'm new to web development. Any suggestions are very welcome, thanks.

[image: test webpage]

Answer (score 1):

Sharing another debugging flow for your question. The result is stored in array, and not from server / network request.

1. **Start with the source of changes** - In your example, the `<div id="content">` is where the result append (changes)
2. **Set a DOM breakpoint** - Right click on the element, select break on > subtree modifications to add a breakpoint to the DOM to track any code modification. You can find the DOM breakpoints you set in the DOM breakpoints** pane.
   [image]
3. **Start debug** - Perform the action (e.g Type `Chicken` and select the first item from the list) to trigger the breakpoint. The code break in `doFunction()`.

[image]

4. **Understand the code**. Read the code, step through debug it then you will realize that the answer is stored in array, and not from server / network request.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question. In short, no network requests because the answer is not coming from server, but it is stored in an array.

Here is how you can find out:

1. **Start debug with the source of action** - In your case, that mean, either start with either of this action:

   - when click on the "Search" button, or
   - when click on the "Banana" in the suggested list
2. **Find out the trigger points** - Inspect these action element in the Elements panel, you will see that:

   - "Search" button triggers `doFunction()` on click
   - "Banana" suggested list item triggers `completeInputValue()` on click
     [image]
3. **Locate the function (part 1)** - Select the trigger element, open the **Event listeners** pane, and find the "click" listener.

   - The hyper link shows you the file name and the line of code
   - Click on the hyperlink should bring you "closer to the source" - either to the file or straight to the line of the javascript function in the Sources panel.

[image]

4. **Locate the function (part 2)** - In our case, the previous link bring us to the element in the `(index)` file, not the function. From here, we can search for the `doFunction()`. There is 2 ways to search:

   - approximate search: use `Command (or Ctrl)` + `F`, and type `doFunction(` or `completeInputValue(` to search for the function
   - accurate search: use `Command (or Ctrl)` + `Shift` + `o` to search for the function (symbol). Type the function name, it tells you the exact line of code.
     [image]
5. **Put a breakpoint and debug** - Put a breakpoint in the function and start debug by perform the same action in step 1 on the page. It should trigger your breakpoint.
6. **Step through the code** - It's time to understand the code line by line. [image]

   - The `myObject` is the array that hold the answer. You can inspect that with the pop up preview, or in the `Scope` section in the sidebar.
   - The `Call Stack` section show you where the function triggers started.

Debugging is an art, with a combination of intuition and experience. You did well in applying your intuitive to check on the Network request! :) Hope you have a good journey learning web dev.

You can checkout the [Chrome DevTools docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/) for more info or follow our [Twitter](https://twitter.com/ChromeDevTools) on latest DevTools update!